# Display results from an MDB file based on a selection using PHP

Tags: php, ms-access, joomla, odbc

I hope someone can help me with this?

I have a Joomla installation running and the website looks and works great.

Here's the problem, the website is for a car dealership, which means they need to display a list of their stock on the floor.

They are using a custom system to manage their stock and this system saves the data to a MS Access database.

I got it to work to a point where I can display a table from the database. (http://www.autodeal.co.za/newsite/used-car-sales-south-africa).

Now when someone clicks on the model, which is a link that will take them to another page which displays only the information relevant to the selected model.

That's what I can't figure out. The link works fine and it takes me to the page that I want, but it doesn't display the data like it's supposed to.

Please see the code below for connecting to the database and displaying the results:

```
    <?php

        $dbName = "F:/Domains/autodeal/autodeal.co.za/wwwroot/newsite/db/savvyautoweb.mdb";

        // Throws an error if the database cannot be found
        if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
            die("Could not find database file.");
        }

        // Connects to the database
        // Assumes there is no username or password
        $conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName", '', '');

        // This is the query
        // You have to have each column you select in the format tableName.[ColumnName]
        $sql = "SELECT Make, Model, Year, Price, SpecialPrice, Branch, StockNO FROM Vehicle ORDER BY Make";

        // Runs the query above in the table
        $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

        echo "\t" . "<tr>\n";

        echo "\t" . "<th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Year</th><th>Price</th><th>Special Price</th><th>Location</th><th>Stock Number</th>" . "\n";

        while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
        {
            $make = odbc_result($rs, Make);
            $model = odbc_result($rs, Model);
            $year = odbc_result($rs, Year);
            $price = odbc_result($rs, Price);
            $specialPrice = odbc_result($rs, SpecialPrice);
            $branch = odbc_result($rs, Branch);
            $stockNo = odbc_result($rs, StockNO);

            echo "\t" . "<tr>\n";
            echo "\t\t" . "<td>" . $make . "</td><td><a href=http://www.autodeal.co.za/newsite/selected-vehicles>" . $model . "</a></td><td>" . $year . "</td><td>" . $price . "</td><td>" . $specialPrice . "</td><td>" . $branch . "</td><td>" . $stockNo . "</td>\n";

            echo "\t" . "</tr>\n";
        }

        odbc_free_result($rs);
        odbc_close($conn);

        // This message is displayed if the query has an error in it
        if (!$rs) {
                exit("There is an error in the SQL!");
        }

    ?>
```

Please see the code below to display a specific vehicle information from the table based on a selection made from the above script.

```
    <?php

        $dbName = "F:/Domains/autodeal/autodeal.co.za/wwwroot/newsite/db/savvyautoweb.mdb";

        // Throws an error if the database cannot be found
        if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
                die("Could not find database file.");
        }

        // Connects to the database
        // Assumes there is no username or password
        $conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName", '', '');

        // This is the query
        // You have to have each column you select in the format tableName.[ColumnName]


        $selected_id = intval($_GET['Id']);
        $sql = "SELECT Id, Make, Model, Year, Price, SpecialPrice, Branch, StockNO, MainPic FROM Vehicle WHERE Id = Id";

        // Runs the query above in the table
        $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

        $id = odbc_result($rs, Id);

        $make = odbc_result($rs, Make);

        $model = odbc_result($rs, Model);

        echo $make;

        echo $model;

        $image_path_main = "<img src=db/vehicleImages/" . $mainPic . "/>";


        echo "this is a test";

        odbc_free_result($rs);
        odbc_close($conn);

        // This message is displayed if the query has an error in it
        if (!$rs) {
                exit("There is an error in the SQL!");
        }

    ?>
```

*EDIT* So I've updated the above code based an answer received, but the individual records aren't displayed. I printed a test line and that works fine, so that tells me that there's an issue with the query? The thing is, the query works fine to display all the records in a table, but I need to display a single record when that record has been clicked.

Furthermore, the $mainPic variable above is referencing the image name from the database. The actual image isn't saved in the database; it's in a different location. I assume I need to create a variable with the actual path of the image and use the reference variables above to display the image, but it's not working.

So to recap, I need some help displaying all information from the database based on a selection.

For example: in the table, I select 323i. On a new page, I need to display all the information that's in the database about the 323i on a new page.

Is that doable and if so, could anyone please assist me in this matter.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using given ID parameter in your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT ... FROM Vehicle WHERE Id = Id ORDER BY Make";
```

you need to get $ID from user and place it into the query like:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']); // assuming it is an integer
$sql = "SELECT ... FROM Vehicle WHERE Id = $id; // no need to order
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I've updated the second block of code based on your answer, but the code isn't working. No it doesn't display anything. I've printed a test line and that worked, so does that mean there's something wrong with the query? Thank you for you assistance.

Comment: It seems you are sending variable as id (lowercase) but using it as $_GET["Id"] (camelcase). This might be the issue.

Comment: I think it does make a difference. In the actual database, the coloumn is called Id (with a capital "I"). I got it to pull something through, but it's not correct. No matter which item I select, it displays the same results. Why would that be? Please see the edited code above (the second block of code).

Comment: It might not make difference on DB but it makes difference when using parameters from $_GET array. I saw another issue: you have id=27 hardcoded in your while loop above.

Comment: That id is the location of the Joomla article. But I changed it and I also changed the $_GET variable. It still displays the wrong information. For instance, when I click on BMW, it's supposed to show me the information of that specific BMW, but instead it shows information for a Renault. I updated the code.

Comment: Then you are not sending any parameter with your URL. You need to send some identifier like Id or ModelName in your href, which is to be retrieved on detail page from $_GET array.

Comment: I'm sorry for being a pain, but how would something like that look?

Comment: You need to modify your query to include Id in selected fields. Then change your URLs to <a href=http://www.autodeal.co.za/newsite/selected-vehicles?Id=$Id>. In detail page you have to change your WHERE query to WHERE Id = $selected_id

Comment: You are an absolute life saver. Thank you so very much for your assistance. It certainly helped a lot. And it worked! I'm sure I'll ask more questions in the very very near future, but for now it's brilliant. Thank you soooo much.